# JS why is other code ignored and only return executed

Tags: javascript, return

I got this code which always gave the same result:

```
var number = 0;
function a(){
    number++; //outside return function
    return function(){
        return number;
    };
}
var b = a(); //outside loop
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    console.log("loop: "+(i+1)+" :"+b());
}
```

I found this solution (1):

```
var number = 0;
function a(){
    number++; //outside return function
    return function(){
        return number;
    };
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    var b = a(); //inside loop
    console.log("loop: "+(i+1)+" :"+b());
}
```

And apparently I should've gotten the "correct" solution (2):

```
var number = 0;
function a(){
    return function(){
        number++; //inside return function
        return number;
    };
}
var b = a(); //outside loop
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    console.log("loop: "+(i+1)+" :"+b());
}
```

In solution 1: I thought that by putting *var b* in the for-loop, it would "refresh" the *var number* with every loop, and it did because every loop a 1 is added.

In solution 2: I don't see why *number++* should be added to the return function to get it looped.
I.m.o. the whole *a()* function is run through just like in the original question and not only the code in its return method? Obviously not, why?

Comment: You might have a look into [variable scope in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Can't quite understand what you're asking. The second solution is better because you're not recreating the whole returnable function again on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version `a()` is only called once, so `number++` is only called once. In the second version you call `a()` with every iteration so `number++` is called on every iteration. So in the first version `b` is always the same function and in the second you get a new one every time you call `a()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Together with your comment about the scope I saw the light.

Answer (score 0):

In (2) the execution of function a returns a function.
Each time you execute this function, 1 is added to the global variable number.

It is the same as when you would have written:

```
function b() {
  number++;
  return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your initial situation is that you only increment the number once by calling `a()` once, and then it returns a function which just returns the number. Any time you call `b()` it will return the number which will always be 1.

In the first solution you call `a()` in every iteration, which will increment the number. The function `b` will then return the number that is incremented by `a`.

In the second solution you basically let `a` generate the function once, and then every iteration `b()` is called which both updates and returns the number value.

I hope this clarifies the problems your having.